# Google Drive API - Permissions - Rate limit exceeded. User message: Sorry, you have exceeded your sharing quota

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been programatically creating and sharing documents using the Google Drive API. Yesterday I started to receive this error message with every request to insert a permission:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
     "domain" : "usageLimits",
     "location" : "user.sharing",
     "locationType" : "other",
     "message" : "Rate limit exceeded. User message: \"Sorry, you have exceeded your sharing quota.\"",
     "reason" : "userRateLimitExceeded"
     } ],
  "message" : "Rate limit exceeded. User message: \"Sorry, you have exceeded your sharing quota.\""
}
```

I can still programatically create documents, but the request to insert a permission always fails.

This is being done through a Service Account, the idea being that the Service Account would manage these documents for an application and share with authorized users as required.

The error started to occur after inserting somewhere around 50-100 permissions. I've done some research and it sounds like there may be a "feature" in the Google Drive API which limits the number of permissions that can be inserted. Is there some way around this limit?

---

Update:

For the record, I'm able to create exactly 51 permissions per day. Creating the 52nd permission always fails for a 24 hour period. Unfortunately this restriction renders the permissions API completely useless for Service Accounts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As already stated by @zdegenr, I also experienced that you can only create about 50 permissions per 24 hours. I could solve this issue by disabling sending notification emails via the `sendNotificationEmails` parameter: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert .

With this configuration I don't hit the quota anymore...

Comment: Thanks, this works! I guess this setting is necessary to prevent using notification emails as spam.

Comment: This does not solve the issue for me. :( With API v2, we make several inserts on the same file but with sendNotificationEmails=False. Yet we reached a quota with very few inserts (probably the 50 daily limit)

Answer (score 1):

Try https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=you+have+exceeded+your+sharing+quota&oq=you+have+exceeded+your+sharing+quota&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8  There are several suggestions in the results, including a mechanism to request support. It's one of either a rate limit error, in which case slow down, or it's a daily quota issue, in which case request a higher quota. Despite what the google docs say, if you're getting a rate limit, do **not** do exponential backoff as it will murder your throughput. Instead throttle your requests to around one every 3s, and then speed up or slow down until they go away.

Comment: Thanks pinoyyid, Ive looked very extensively through those results. One of the pages suggests there is a hidden daily limit on the number of shares allowed to prevent spam (via the notification email I guess): [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/docs/documents/9Rnt5BS-qmI) . If that is the case though then I'm not sure Google Drive can be used to programmatically share files with certain users...

Comment: Not sure why you suggest to avoid exponential backoff. Always worked great for me. Fixing it at 3 requests per second will not scale well and you are hardcoding the wait while with backoff its a dinamic wait.

Comment: @ZigMandel. Exponential backoff works for some categories of error, but not rate limit. By definition, rate limit errors occur when a client is attempting to submit a high volume of transactions, let's say 1,000 for the purpose of discussion. The goal of the app is therefore to submit 1,000 transactions in the minimum elapsed time, ie at the highest available throughput. Your app will submit 30 or so in rapid succession without failure. After the 30, each successive transaction will fail 403 until you start throttling down to the rate permitted by Google. ...

Comment: ... If you backoff by less than the internal Google token refresh rate (gtrr), your re-attempt will also fail, and the attempt after that, until your backoff delay exceeds the gtrr. So you've sent 2-3 attempts before one succeeds, and each subsequent attempt (remember we've so far sent 31 and are trying to send 1,000) will also fail, repeat, repeat. So the result is wasted bandwidth, wasted Google server load, and a lousy user experience as he waits for the 1,000 transactions at roughly one every 6s....

Comment: ...The correct approach is to throttle transactions to the gtrr, which is a secret number, but empirically around 1.5-2s. If you carefully re-read my answer, you'll see it says "one every 3s, and then speed up or slow down until they go away.", ie. dyamically adjust the transaction rate until it matches the gtrr. 3s is simply a safe starting point based on a bunch of extensive benchmarking I carried out. So, tl;dr, don't use exponential back off for 403 rate limit errors. It's the wrong tool for that task.

Comment: You dont have to reset your delay right away after success instead you could keep dividing by two until it fails and also stay at the wait that last succeeded for a while. This works great when many parallel requests happen without a known pattern. If instead you have a single task using the api then yes its best to hardcode it to the published rate (which can be changed in the api console for some scopes)

Comment: "hardcode it to the published rate" - 1) hardcoding is bad and 2) there is no published rate and 3) it can't be changed. I think you're confusing rate limit with quota limit, two very different things. Fixing the retry rate at the delay value that last succeeded is bogus. Ignoring jitter, that figure will either be 2s which is probably too low, or 4s which is too high.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation is .NET

```
var permissionsBody = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.Permission()
{
    Type = "user",
    Role = "reader",
    EmailAddress = "emailAddress",
 };
 var permission = _service.Permissions.Create(permissionsBody, fileId);
 permission.SendNotificationEmail = false;
 permission.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting a quota per second limit. You can only make so many requests at one time. Implement [Exponential Backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors#implementing_exponential_backoff), so that when you fail requests, you will give it a little time before re-trying. It should reduce the amount of rate limit errors you see.

Comment: I tried adding a 10 second delay before adding the permission and the same error was encountered. About an hour ago I was able to add permissions again (appears to be a 24 hour lock out), so I tried programmatically adding 100 document and 100 permissions, a new document every 2 seconds. Somewhere around the 50th iteration I was locked out again.