# What is the daily file sharing limit in the google cloud API and how do I raise it?

Tags: google-drive-api

I get this error:

```
{'errors': [{'domain': 'usageLimits', 'reason': 'userRateLimitExceeded', 'message': 'Rate limit exceeded. User message: "Sorry, you have exceeded your sharing quota."', 'locationType': 'other', 'location': 'user.sharing'}], 'code': 403, 'message': 'Rate limit exceeded. User message: "Sorry, you have exceeded your sharing quota."'}
```

But I can't see this limit in the cloud console. It seems like the daily limit is 100 files, but I need to raise it for my application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Drive API - Permissions - Rate limit exceeded. User message: Sorry, you have exceeded your sharing quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630595/google-drive-api-permissions-rate-limit-exceeded-user-message-sorry-you-h)

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Check the quotas

Confirm what's the specific API you're calling and [monitor](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301355) it

### 2. Limits are by request not by files

You have a [limit](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10445916?hl=en#:%7E:text=The%20default%20quota%20limits%20for,these%20quotas%2C%20request%20an%20increase.) of 10,000 every 100 seconds per project per user, so it's likely you're making a lot of requests in a short period of time

### 3. Implement exponential backoff

An [exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/exponential-backoff) algorithm retries requests exponentially, increasing the waiting time between retries up to a maximum backoff time

### 4. If all of the above is already checked, request an increase

- Go to the Cloud Console and sign in as a Google Workspace super administrator.
- From the Project list, select the project you're using for the migration.
- On the left, click IAM & admin > Quotas.
- Using the checkboxes, select one or more quotas to edit, then click Edit Quotas.
  Note: Billing must be enabled on the project in order to click the checkboxes.
- In the Edit Quotas panel on the right, complete the form with your Name, Email, and Phone details, then click Next.
- In the Edit Quotas panel, select the service to expand the view, then edit the quotas in that service to your requested limit. Click Done.
- Click Submit request.